# App crashes when i click the button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

I am only a day old in using android studio. I have to create an app for my school project, i did that, i programmed it and everything went fine but when i run it via adb get the expected main activity and when i click the button to go to another activity it crashes saying "unfortunately, appname has stopped working"

```
package com.example.lenovo.shop_easy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class frontpagee extends Activity

{
public void sendMessage(View view){
Intent intent = new Intent(frontpagee.this, catalog.class);
startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_frontpagee, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

the XML goes like this

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"          android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"                               tools:context=".frontpagee"
 android:background="@drawable/back">

<ImageView
android:layout_width="472dp"
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView11"
android:src="@mipmap/cover"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
android:contentDescription="@string/content" />

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/text12"
android:id="@+id/button11"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
android:textSize="@dimen/size2"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

i want to move from this activity to the second ACTIVITY which is named Catalog java is

```
 package com.example.lenovo.shop_easy;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;

 public class catalog extends Activity {

 @Override

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_catalog, menu);
 return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
 // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
 // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(catalog.this, product1.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
public void sendMessage1(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(catalog.this, PRODUCT2.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
public void sendMessage2(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(catalog.this, PRODUCT3.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
public void sendMessage3(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(catalog.this, product4.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
public void sendMessage4(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(catalog.this, product5.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
public void sendMessage5(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(catalog.this, product6.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
public void sendMessage6(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(catalog.this, product7.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
public void sendMessage7(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(catalog.this, product8.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
public void sendMessage8(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(catalog.this, product9.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
public void sendMessage9(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(catalog.this, product10.class);
startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

the code is correct says android studio but when i run the adb on my phone it installs the app, everything goes fine but when i open the app it displays the main activity but when i click on the button it crashes. please help

and here the main xml file also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lenovo.shop_easy" >

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".frontpagee"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".catalog"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_catalog" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".product1"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_product1" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".PRODUCT2"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_product2" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".PRODUCT3"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_product3" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".product4"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_product4" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".product5"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_product5" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".product6"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_product6" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".product7"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_product7" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".product8"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_product8" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".product9"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_product9" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".product10"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_product10" >
</activity>
</application>


</manifest>
```

what to do

here are the logcat

```
    09-06 21:28:40.349  19239-19239/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-06 21:28:40.359  19239-19245/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
09-06 21:28:40.569  19239-19239/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 55K, 77% free 2619K/10920K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
09-06 21:28:40.609  19239-19239/? I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 13.315MB for 9002464-byte allocation
09-06 21:28:40.639  19239-19243/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 43% free 11409K/19712K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 24ms
09-06 21:28:40.759  19239-19239/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 43% free 11409K/19712K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
09-06 21:28:40.789  19239-19239/? I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.577MB for 16004368-byte allocation
09-06 21:28:40.839  19239-19243/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 24% free 27039K/35344K, paused 4ms+8ms, total 51ms
09-06 21:28:40.969  19239-19239/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8803K, 45% free 19530K/35344K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
09-06 21:28:40.989  19239-19239/? I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 33.244MB for 12582928-byte allocation
09-06 21:28:41.019  19239-19243/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 34% free 31815K/47636K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 30ms
09-06 21:28:41.079  19239-19239/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 34% free 31815K/47636K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
09-06 21:28:41.150  19239-19239/? I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 81.242MB for 50331664-byte allocation
09-06 21:28:41.170  19239-19243/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 17% free 80967K/96792K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 25ms
09-06 21:28:41.650  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13509K, 24% free 74167K/96792K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
09-06 21:28:41.720  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1107K, 19% free 79047K/96792K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
09-06 21:28:41.780  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 977K, 14% free 84144K/96792K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
09-06 21:28:41.780  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 8856592-byte allocation
09-06 21:28:41.800  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 14% free 84135K/96792K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
09-06 21:28:41.800  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 8856592-byte allocation.
09-06 21:28:41.800  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
09-06 21:28:41.800  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41788728 self=0x41773600
09-06 21:28:41.800  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=19239 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074515964
09-06 21:28:41.800  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=72 stm=18 core=0
09-06 21:28:41.800  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
09-06 21:28:41.800  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
09-06 21:28:41.800  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:816)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2117)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:127)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:117)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.example.lenovo.shop_easy.catalog.onCreate(catalog.java:16)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
09-06 21:28:41.830  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 21:28:41.840  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-06 21:28:41.840  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
09-06 21:28:41.840  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
09-06 21:28:41.840  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 21:28:41.840  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 09-06 21:28:41.840 19239:19239 D/skia     ]
    --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
09-06 21:28:41.840  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-06 21:28:41.840  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417878b0)
09-06 21:28:41.840  19239-19239/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lenovo.shop_easy/com.example.lenovo.shop_easy.catalog}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #179: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #179: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
            at com.example.lenovo.shop_easy.catalog.onCreate(catalog.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
            at com.example.lenovo.shop_easy.catalog.onCreate(catalog.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:816)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2117)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:127)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:117)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
            at com.example.lenovo.shop_easy.catalog.onCreate(catalog.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I dont think you have set Oncreate in your frontpagee activity.

Comment: i have added Oncreatoption menu, i think you mean something different please specify

Comment: ok i got it, Now i have added that onCreatBundle and added to activity but no result i still get the same error

Comment: Are you executing on your phone from an IDE (like Android Studio or Eclipse)? You should copy and paste on your answer the LogCat of the error so that you could see what's going on.

Comment: can you paste the logs related to the crash?

Comment: What to do?  Well, I'd start by showing the actual exception!

Comment: i have posted the logcats i get the same error still, i would try that onclicklistener method but please suggest something like send Message

Comment: Please paste the xml code for catalog activity. Looks to be an issue with Image referenced in it.

Answer (score 0):

In android menifest.xml file, add the relevant activity

```
<activity android:name="ListViewImage"></activity>
<activity android:name="com.company.listview.ListViewImage">
</activity>
```

In your main activity, call the onclicklistner for your button click event as described below.

```
Button btnClickToNext;
btnClickToNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_Liste);

btnClickToNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{    
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, catalog.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 });
```

hope, it works absolutely fine for you, and any help will be needed, kindly keep in touch with me, have great day ahead.